# Select values from enum using multiple where clauses

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to select list of items (Bwm and Audi only) from CarBrands enum

```
    public enum CarBrands
    {
        [Description("BMW")] Bmw = 1,
        [Description("AUDI")] Audi = 2,
        [Description("TOYOTA")] Toyota = 3,
    }

var test = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarBrands)).Cast<CarBrands>();

var test2 = from t in carBrands
            .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Bmw)
            .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Audi)
            select test2 ;

        var test3 = carBrands
             .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Bmw)
             .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Audi)
             .ToList();
```

This returns empty result no selected values from carBrands list.

Comment: `return new List<CarBrands> { CarBrands.Bmw, CarBrands.Audi };`

Comment: As hinted at by the other comment, combining `Where` like you are implements `and` logic. You want `or` logic to select both values.

Comment: Or, said another way, the first `Where` filters the collection down to `BMW`. The second `Where` then takes the list that contains only `BMW`, and filters it down to only `Audi`. There being no `BMW` that is also an `Audi`, the result is an empty collection

Comment: FYI To read attributes from an enum, you need to use reflection to read the static fields of the enum type; `typeof(CarBrands).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple `Where` clauses represent `AND` logic, you can create "filter" array and use `Contains`:

```cs
var brandsArray = new[] { CarBrands.Bmw, CarBrands.Audi };
var test3 = carBrands
    .Where(x => brandsArray.Contains(x))
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var test3 = carBrands
    .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Bmw || x == CarBrands.Audi)
    .ToList();
```

P.S.

There is generic version of [`Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-7.0#system-enum-getvalues-1) available since .NET 5 which can be used to simplify the code:

```cs
var carBrands = Enum.GetValues<CarBrands>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need Linq to create a list of two known items:

```
return new List<CarBrands> { CarBrands.Bmw, CarBrands.Audi };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

```
var test = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarBrands)).Cast<CarBrands>();

var test2 = from t in test
            .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Bmw || x == CarBrands.Audi)
            select t;
```

or

```
var test3 = from t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarBrands)).Cast<CarBrands>()
                        .Where(x => x == CarBrands.Bmw || x == CarBrands.Audi)
                        select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

While the current answers provide good approaches for accomplishing your scenario, one thing worth pointing out is they all rely on reflection and all can have serious performance cost especially if being run in a hot code path.

If these are values you plan to reference often (and I’m assuming you will), make sure you cache the enum to string map so you only take a one-time hit for allocation and discovery since these things are not going to change during the program’s lifetime.

Better yet, if you’re not doing bitwise operations or aren’t needing to convert the enum values to integers, just use `const` strings instead and reference those values. You can use a resx file to to provide localized mappings if needed.